# Convert ActionResult to a URL string in a static method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I have access to UrlHelper I can convert an ActionResult to a string (i.e. the actual URL) like this: urlHelper.RouteUrl(actionResult.GetRouteValueDictionary());

How can I do that same from a static method where I don't have access to UrlHelper? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add a using statement for System.Web.Mvc, and create an instance of the UrlHelper class in your static method.

Comment: I was hoping there was something hidden somewhere that I could use without instantiating a UrlHelper...

Comment: The need to perform the instantiation is implied in your question.  It's not a big class.  I suppose you could lift the relevant code from the class using Reflector, but that would essentially amount to the same thing.

Comment: By instantiating the class, you benefit from using the class in its pristine, tested form, and you get access to all of the RouteUrl overloads.

Comment: OK... how do I instantiate a UrlHelper class, i.e. it expects a RequestContext object? How can I get a hold of that? Is it somewhere in HttpContext.Current?

Comment: What I'm working on is an HTML helper, so I have an instance to HtmlHelper, in this case I can write new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext); It would be nice to know how to get a hold of this RequestContext without htmlHelper...

Comment: That's probably the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have rendered a partial result with a method like this.

```
private string RenderPartialViewToString(ControllerContext context, string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            viewName = context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        ViewData.Model = model;

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(context, viewName);
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(context, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```